Add Tlog columns in target table (AWS DMS CDC task)
I have a DMS task for cdc running and working fine. Source and target both are MSSQL. I can see the changed data in target table however, I want additional tlog columns which will give me information like timestamps and what operation it did etc.
How can I achieve that?
I tried reading documentation from aws website but I couldn't reach to the conclusion.
